# Jenkis changes log trims commit comments

Tags: git, jenkins, commit

I'm using Jenkins to build my software projects.  It has a "Changes" log where it shows all the commit comments for each commit per build.  For example, build #316 and #315 had only 1 commit but build #314 had 3 commits.  The problem is, Jenkins trims the commit comments to only one line.  So any text in the commit comments after a carriage return gets cut off and not displayed.  I want to display the entire commit comments regardless of length.  Can I do that with Jenkins?  The alternative would be to write a bash script myself to do this based on tags, but i'd rather not since Jenkins is doing this for me.

[image]

Comment: So you need the commits in relation to a specific build is that right? I havnt seen any functionality for that in jenkins and looking at the repository is out of the question because it wont show you the build its for. Good question +1

Comment: Yes that's correct.  Trying to find an easy off the shelf way of grabbing all commit comments that go into a specific build.  The change log in Jenkins does exactly what I want, but it trims the text to only one line per comment :-( Obviously production ready release notes would be hand typed, but for dev builds commit comments are perfect.

Comment: Which version of Jenkins you are on? I am on 1.565.3 and I am able to see comments in full.

Comment: @NotAgain I'm on Jenkins ver. 1.607